# JDBCtemplate : getting the inserted data's autogenerated key

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I was wondering, how can i get the my inserted data's Id using jdbctemplate? I can do this in Php but i don't know how to do it in java. 
I searched into the docs and found out about the executeAndReturnKey(..) but my jdbctemplate does not recognize this class (only .execute()).

pls. help me

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with example.

Comment: Are you using `Spring`'s `JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: "but my jdbctemplate does not recognize this class (only .execute())". That is correct. `JdbcTemplate` does not have executeAndReturnKey() method. That method is in `SimpleJdbcInsert` class. Take a look at this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch13s05.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`KeyHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/KeyHolder.html) with `JdbcTemplate`,

```
KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("Your Insert/Update Query", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        // set values in query
        return statement;
    }
}, generatedKeyHolder);

Number id = generatedKeyHolder.getKey();
// Use this Number to get id with feasible type long, int etc.
// For example,
// int myId = id.intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)  
                                    .withTableName("EMPLOYEE")  
                                    .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID");  


Number id = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);  
System.out.println("Generated id - " + id.longValue());
```